# Unexpected token var when inside a function

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a XmlHttpRequest that works when its outside a function, if I then put it inside I get that row 94 has `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var .`

My row 94 is `var xmlhttp;`

I have google around and look at other functions it it should work ?

Any ideas ? this is what i have for now.

```
function run(){
readXml();
}

function readXML{

var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("get", 'xml/stickers.xml', false);
xmlhttp.send();
var myXML = xmlhttp.responseXML;
stickers = myXML.getElementsByTagName("sticker");
for( i = 0; i<stickers.length; i++){

var idNod =  (stickers[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); /*Get the ID*/
var id = idNod;
var textNod = (stickers[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); /* Text*/
add_sticker(textNod);  /*Call creator function*/

var Xnod =  (stickers[i].getElementsByTagName("x")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)+'px';      /*Get the x position Add PX for pixel*/
var Ynod =  (stickers[i].getElementsByTagName("y")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)+'px';     /*Get the y position*/
var Znod =  (stickers[i].getElementsByTagName("z")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);     /*Get the y position*/
//console.log(Ynod)
//console.log(Xnod)

document.getElementById(id).style.top=Ynod;   /* Style the position if the div. well done */
document.getElementById(id).style.left=Xnod;
document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex=Znod;

} }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `()`:

```
function readXML() {
// Here --------^
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the () in the function declaration

```
function readXML() {

  var xmlhttp;
  ...
```